# Carrying a pocket handkerchief on Shabas

Tags: halacha, clothing, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

The general rule is that one cannot go outside (an *eruv*) on *Shabas* with something unless it is a garment or "adornment" ("תכשיט", like jewelry), or part of a garment or adornment. There are many details; see e.g. *Shulchan Aruch*, *OC* 301 and 303, and consult your rabbi with any specific questions.

Among the things permitted, however, is a certain object which is carried around as protection against miscarrying. This is permitted even for a woman who is not yet currently pregnant. (*SA* 303:24. Again, consult your rabbi for practical guidance.) We see here that, at least sometimes, something may be taken outside even though it is not worn at all but carried.

*Mishna B'rura* 301:84 notes included in the prohibition is that one may not go outside with a handkerchief in his pocket ("‏…בזמנינו שאין דרך להיות הפאציילע״ט תפור בהבגד לא בטיל הוא לגבי בגד ואסור…‏"). The reasoning is that it is not a garment or adornment, but functional.

What about a handkerchief that *is* adornment? Suppose people keep handkerchiefs in their suit pockets purely for adornment and would never dream of using them for anything. Could they then walk outside with such handkerchiefs on *Shabas*?

Comment: 631 http://www.halachos.com/halacha/hal_601_700.asp No idea who wrote that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shemirat Shabbat KeHilchatah (3rd edition (5770), 18:25) permits (for those who are generally lenient about carrying jewelry) a man to wear a "handkerchief exclusively designated for adornment in the upper pocket" (my translation) in a public domain. Sounds like your case.

Comment: I assume you mean "for those who are generally lenient about wearing jewelry"?

Comment: @msh210 היינו הך :)